# USB 2.0 not recognized by USB 3.0

Tags: windows-8, printer, usb-3, hp-laserjet

My old HP Laserjet 1005 USB 2.0 Printer is not recognized by my new DELL USB 3.0 socket. 
Printer is too good to replace.

Comment: Does the printer show up as unknown USB device in the device Manager? Some Printers require the drivers installed before connected via USB.

Comment: I tried so many ways. The install of the driver asks for the printer to be connected. I connect it. It does not see it and the only thing to do is stop the install, then it uninstall everything.

Comment: I had a different cable from a Cannon printer - same problem.

Comment: I think the most success I had was when I tried installing the Win 7.0 Driver - even tough it is a WIn 8.1 system.

Comment: Does any other device, e.g. a memory stick, work in the USB 3.0 socket on the computer? Some people report successful methods at [Windows 8.1 upgrade - now my LaserJet P1005 printer wont work (AGAIN!!!!!)](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-All-in-One-Software-Drivers/Windows-8-1-upgrade-now-my-LaserJet-P1005-printer-wont-work/td-p/3028121).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a late response, but it might still help you or others. My old HP LaserJet4050T has a parallel printer port which I tried to connect to my computer's USB3.0 port with a parallel-to-USB cord (which is USB2.0). I kept running into issues. What worked was first plugging this USB2.0 cord into an old USB2.0 hub I had and then plugging that into my USB3.0 computer port.

The cord is an ATEN UC-1284B (driver for this cable automatically recognized and installed on Windows 10) and I chose to install the printer driver manually from the list of printer drivers within the Windows dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

The [HP Support website](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?cc=us&cc=us&lang=en&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=214538&ac.admitted=1416425898505.876444892.199480143) does not list drivers for anything above Windows XP. This would lead me to believe that the printer you are trying to use is not compatible with the new Dell running Windows 8.1 as stated above in the comments of your question. I would recommend either a network print server device or share the printer to the network from a workstation using a compatible operating system.

Comment: Its not even clear if the author even attempts to install the printer, because Windows 8 is suppose to have the capability, to install generic printer drivers for basic printing support for a great majority of printers.

Comment: Thanks alot. However a driver is available from HP site for Win 8.1.

Comment: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&product=3435676                            DRIVER FOR WIN 8.1 for my printer. Problem is USB 2.0 cable to printer not seen by usb 3.0 socket.

Comment: The link you just provided is for an HP LaserJet **P1005** Printer. That is not the same printer as you described in your question originally.